# Points of bounded height in a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field of absolute degree $d$, let $B$ be a positive real number, and write $S(K, B) = \{x \in K : H(x) \leq B\}$. Here $H$ is the absolute multiplicative height of an algebraic number. A result of Schanuel asserts that $|S(K, B)| \sim c B^{2d}$ for some explicit constant $c$ depending only on the number field $K$.

Does anyone know if the proof of Schanuel's result can be turned into an algorithm for computing the set $S(K,B)$?

There are other approaches to computing the set $S(K,B)$. For example, the article "Elements with bounded height in number fields" by Petho and Schmitt [Period. Math. Hungar. 43 (2001), no. 1-2, 31–41] gives an algorithm that embeds $S(K,B)$ into a computable set of size $B^{2d^2 + d}$. But sorting through this larger set to determine $S(K,B)$ is computationally infeasible for quadratic fields when $B$ is larger than about 3.

NB - The simplest definition of the absolute multiplicative height is via the Mahler measure of its minimal polynomial. Suppose $x \in K$ has minimal polynomial $f(T) \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$, and write $$f(T)= a(T-\alpha_1) \cdots (T - \alpha_r)$$ with $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $x = \alpha_1$. Then the absolute multiplicative height $H(x)$ can be defined by the formula
$$
H(x)^r =  |a| \prod_{i = 1}^r \max\{1, |\alpha_i|\}.
$$

P.S. To clarify, I already have an algorithm in hand that calculates the set $S(K,B)$ fairly quickly, but I am specifically interested in knowing whether or not Schanuel's technique can be reworked into an algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps you should define "the absolute multiplicative height of an algebraic number" just for the education of those less versed in this area.  Is it $n + \sum |a_i|$ where the $a_i$ are the coefficients of the min degree polynomial of which it is a root?

Comment: @Xander: Thanks for adding the definition!

Comment: Maybe applying BKZ to a basis of the integer ring divided by $a$, varying over $a$, will work?

Comment: @Dror: what is BKZ?

Comment: Block korkine-zolotareff reduction, slightly stronger than LLL. It interpolates between LLL and HKZ (hermite).

Comment: Once you have a nice basis $L$ for the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, you still need to use some kind of algebraic number theory to turn a height bound into bounds for the coefficients of an element $x \in K$, as written in the basis $L$. The paper by Petho/Schmitt that I mentioned above uses exactly this strategy, but their bounds for the coefficients are fairly weak. 

Comment: @Xander: Do you actually want the full set $S(K,B)$, or do you have some other problem such as a Diophantine equation whose solutions you know have height less than $B$, and you want to find the solutions? If the latter, there are often tricks to cut the search space. As for Schanuel's proof, my impression is that if it's done carefully with error estimates, it will yield an algorithm, but I don't imagine it would be at all efficient. (However, I haven't actually tried to do it.)

Comment: @Joe: I want the full set $S(K, B)$ for a very general implementation in Sage. This is also the reason for fixing the number field, rather than ranging over all number fields of bounded degree as one might expect from Northcott's theorem.

Comment: The polynomials $a_dx^d+\dots+a_1x+a_0$ of degree $d$ with Mahler measure $\leq B$ always have $|a_i|\leq \min\{\binom{d}{i}, \binom{d}{d-i}\}B$, shouldn't this restrict the search space to at most $d(2^{d/2}B)^{d+1}$ total roots?

Comment: @Maurizio: Oh my, you're right! Your bound is too small to be compatible with Schanuel's theorem ... but that's because I forgot to normalize my definition of the height correctly. (It has been corrected.) With the extra exponent on the H(x), it follows that if one searches over all irreducible polynomials of degree $d$, then the search space of roots has size at most $d(2^{d/2} B^d)^{d+1}$. I believe that this is also roughly equivalent to the approach by Petho and Schmitt. 

Comment: @Xander: ah ok, now it is clear where the d2 in the exponent was coming from. And unluckily at the moment i have no better idea.